# Using webpack for angular app without ES6. TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to convert our Angular app which is using Grunt to use webpack.

And i am getting the following Error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 9b19609cd4b35f075583:50(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:5__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 9b19609cd4b35f075583:50webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 9b19609cd4b35f075583:21(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:1
```

and here is the bootstrap.js i have

```
'use strict';

require('./vendor')();

var appModule = require('./app');

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('App Module Name=['+appModule.name+']');
    angular.bootstrap(document, [appModule.name], {

    });
});
```

and my vendor.js file

```
module.exports = function(){
    require('angular');
}
```

my webpack.config.js file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var APP  = __dirname + '/src';

module.exports = {

    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')
    },
    context  : APP,
    entry : {
       app : ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './app/bootstrap.js']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: APP,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase : './dist',
        colors:true,
        histroryApiFallback :true,
        inline: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'exports?angular'},
            {test: /\.tpl\.html$/, loader: 'raw'},
            {test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css'},
            {test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less'}
        ]
    }

};
```

In the dev console here is where i am getting the Error:

```
// Execute the module function
        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong..

Thanks

Comment: i changed the loaders in my webpack.config.js to                                        {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'imports?angular'}, and then i am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function !!

Comment: Are you wanting explicitly to not use ES6?

Comment: Yes it is an existing app and we don't want to rewrite it in ES6 yet. It was using grunt and wanted to migrate to webpack.

Comment: You know you can still use Babel loader etc and not have to write ES6